# PUT on SAS blob url without specifying x-ms-blob-type header?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

Is there a way to generate an SAS url that doesn't require specifying the x-ms-blob-type header?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a way to generate an SAS url that doesn't require specifying
>   the x-ms-blob-type header?

As of today, NO. You can't create a SAS URL that can only be used to upload a specific type of blob (Block, Page or Append). Type of blob is determined at the time of upload via `x-ms-blob-type` header.

Comment: That makes it effectively useless as opaque URLs to hand out for PUT requests. Do you know if this was improved since?

Comment: AFAIK, it is still the case. Blob type is specified at upload time. May I know why you say that this functionality is useless?

Comment: E.g. if you have a service which allows different kinds of backends for its blobstores (S3, GCP, Azure, etc.), and you want to generate opaque URLs and hand them out to third-party clients to upload something, the actual client uploading the blob needs to know to which backend it is uploading to. The other blobstore providers seem to be happy with a simple PUT request, no special headers needed.

Comment: `The other blobstore providers seem to be happy with a simple PUT request, no special headers needed.` - Could this be because they only have one type of object (S3 and GCP at least) where as Azure has 3 blob types (Block, Page and Append)? I think each storage provider is somewhat different. For example, if you want to upload a really large file in S3, you would need to implement their `Upload Part` REST API. I think somewhere nuances specific to a particular provider would come in picture.

Comment: Fair enough. I'm just wondering why the SAS URL doesn't simply get another query parameter that specifies what kind of blobs it accepts.

Comment: Good point! While we're at it, I would very much like to see restriction on the  max size of the file that can be uploaded using this SAS URL.

Comment: If you want this to be added to storage; vote for it:
https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217298-storage/suggestions/11387868-add-x-ms-request-headers-in-shared-access-signatu

Comment: Looks like the previous feedback URL broke. Here’s the current version: https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/b0b54fd6-3525-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f0f84